# Problem configuring the GPIO on STM32F103 using assembly

Tags: assembly, stm32, keil, stm32f1

My objective is to write bare metal assembly code for STM32F103 that turns PB1 LED on.
The steps I follow is listed below:
1. Enable IOPB Bit 3 in RCC_APB2ENR registry which has 0x18 address reset from RCC Base address 0x40021000. (Reset value of this registry is 0x00000000)
2. Enable CNF1(00):7-6 bits and MODE1(10):5-4bits for PB1 in GPIO_CRL registry, which reset values is 0x44444444 and its address is 0x0 offset from GPIO_BASE address 0x40010C00. This configuration sets port to General purpose output push-pull with 2MHz max speed.
3. Set bit 1 - ODR1 in GPIOx_ODR registry which is 0x0C offset from GPIO_BASE and its reset value is 0x00000000.

```
   stack_size      EQU      0x400 ; 0x400 = 1024 byte = 1kB
   stack_start     EQU      0x20000000 + stack_size
   gpiob_base      EQU      0x40010C00
   rcc_base        EQU      0x40021000
   rcc_apb2enr     EQU      rcc_base+0x18
   gpio_crl        EQU      gpiob_base
   gpiob_odr       EQU      gpiob_base+0x0C


            PRESERVE8
            THUMB 
            
            AREA RESET, DATA, READONLY
            DCD stack_start 
            DCD __mainCode              
            AREA |.text|, CODE, READONLY 
            ENTRY   
   __mainCode   PROC 
                LDR R0, =rcc_apb2enr
                LDR R1, [R0]
                LDR R2, =0x4
                ORR R1, R2
                STR R1, [R0]
                
                ; Configure GPIO_CRL
                LDR R0, =gpio_crl
                LDR R1, [R0]
                LDR R2, =0xFFFFFF00
                AND R1,R1,R2
                ORR R1, R1, #0x20
                STR R1, [R0] ; Reset register

                ; Configure GPIOB_ODR
                LDR R0, =gpiob_odr
                LDR R1, [R0]
                ORR R1, #0x2
                STR R1, [R0]
                NOP
            ENDP 
            ALIGN
            END
```

Unfortunately the code does not turns led on. I have debugged the code and noticed the following.

1. After reset the value of GPIO_CRL has to be 0x44444444, however it is 0x44444844

[image]

2. GPIO_ODR registry value has to be 0x00000000 but it is also 0x00000001
   After I ORR this value with 0x2 and want to store back to its registry address 0x40010C0C
   its value remains (0x00000001) unchanged.

[image]

Kindly advise what's wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: _"Enable IOPB Bit 3 in RCC_APB2ENR"_. In your code you're setting bit 2 (IOPAEN).

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Reset value of every register is mentioned on top of the register in Reference Manual (Attached is snap below).
[image]

===============================================

Wherever there are multi-bit parameters in registers, I am making a habbit of clearing them first and then applying a desired NON Zero value.

In case of setting Zero values, there is no need for clearing them. You are already clearing it.

here is a sample code i use.

```
////Clearing the bit masks. Need to keep it a practice at all multibit parameters
GPIOA->CRL=(GPIOA->CRL & ~((3U<<GPIO_CRL_CNF7_Pos) | (3U<<GPIO_CRL_CNF5_Pos)))
        | (2U<<GPIO_CRL_CNF7_Pos) | (2U<<GPIO_CRL_CNF5_Pos);//setting desired values
```

Here in above code, I want to set Configuration of PA7 & PA5 to Alternate Port function (Push-Pull).

So I cleared those bits and then set the desired value.

If i wanted to set a Zero in these bits, then I can simply write as below (Written for PC13)

```
GPIOC->CRH |= (GPIOC->CRH & ~(1U<<GPIO_CRH_CNF13_Pos)) | (2U<<GPIO_CRH_MODE13_Pos);     //LED PIN
```